# Get distinct values from a comma-delimited column in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a MySQL table that consists of comma-delimited strings. I would like to convert this column into a set of distinct strings that occur in the column (for any row in the table -- the set includes strings that occur in any row of the table in this column). What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

The solution doesn't need to be pure MySQL. It could involve unix, perl, etc.

Comment: Well, MySQL doesn't have any functions to split strings. It'll be quite a challenge to split your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I chose was to run the select mysql command outside of the mysql shell and pipe the results into tr and sort --uniq

```
mysql my_db [-p -u -h] -se "select my_column from my_table;" | tr ',' '\n' | sort -u
```

This is pretty simple and seems to give the correct results as far as I can tell.

Comment: Nice one-liner! I would recommend using the -s flag with mysql to avoid the column header being mixed in with the output. Also if you specify the db then you don't need to use `use my_db;`. Like so: `mysql my_db [-p -u -h] -se "select my_column from my_table;" |  tr ',' '\n' | sort -u`

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get a quick-and-dirty list of distinct strings from a comma-delimited column using `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`, `sed`, and `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Basically you want to dump the text data to a flat file, using a comma as the line delimiter so each string will be treated as a separate row when you load it back into the database. Then load the extracted into a new table and select the distinct values.

Off the top of my head, the code would look something like this:

```
select str 
into outfile
'/tmp/your_table_data.txt'
lines terminated by ','
from your_table;

sed -e 's/\\,/,/g' -e 's/,$//' /tmp/your_table_data.txt >  /tmp/commadelimited.txt

create table your_table_parsed(str text);

load data infile '/tmp/commadelimited.txt' 
ignore into table your_table_parsed 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by ',';

select distinct str from your_table_parsed;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (+1). Ultimately, I opted for a solution that operated outside of mysql.